# How to create responsive layout in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, layout, bootstrap-4

I was trying to create a responsive layout like the screenshot using Bootstrap 4 but having some problems with making the sidebar and bottom bar fixed and also not able to change the size of bottom bar.Also both main and sidebar have individual overflow scrolling.

1. fixed top nav bar >done
2. fixed side bar
3. fixed bottom bar > done
4. bottom bar size should be same as main body

Expected output
[image]

Here is the code whatever i have done so far

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <!-- Top Nav Bar -->
  <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">logo</a>
    


   

    
  </nav>

  <!-- main body -->
  <div class="container-fluid h-100" >
    <div class="row h-100">

      <!-- left body -->
      <div class="col-sm-10" style="background-color: #F0F2F5;">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:80px">
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- side nav Bar -->
      <div class="col-sm-2 border" style="margin-top:55px;" >
        <h5>list</h5>
        <hr>
        <h1>some text</h1>
        <h1>some text</h1>
        <h1>some text</h1>
        <h1>some text</h1>
        <h1>some text</h1>
        <h1>some text</h1>
        <h1>some text</h1>
        <h1>some text</h1>
        <h1>some text</h1>
        <h1>some text</h1>
        <h1>some text</h1>
        <h1>some text</h1>
        <h1>some text</h1>
        <h1>some text</h1>
        
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- bottom player -->
  <nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-dark bg-dark" >
    <div class="container" style="width: 50%;height: 40px;">


    </div>
  </nav>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We removed the inline style from all elements. We added style in sidebar `.sidebar-content` as `position: fixed;` and sets its position as per your requirement. We also added style in `.content-main`, in that we make it as scrollable content and set padding as per your need further we gave width to `.footer`(bottom bar) same as a
`.content-main` (main body).

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/14ybmh92/7/

```css
body {
    background-color: #F0F2F5;
  }
  main { 
    padding: 56px 0;
  }
  nav.header{ 
      z-index: 1060;
  }
.row .sidebar-content{
    
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;  
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: calc(100% - 56px);
    z-index: 1050;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.content-main{
   
    height:calc(100vh - 112px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.footer{ 
    max-width: calc(100% - 16.666667%);
}

@media (max-width:767px)

/* for mobile */
  {
  .sidebar-content {
    position: unset;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #fff;
  }


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }

  </style>

  <body>
    <!-- Top Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">logo</a>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <!-- main body -->
      <div class="container-fluid h-100">
        <div class="row h-100">

          <!-- left body -->
          <div class="col-sm-10 content-main">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
              <h1>some text</h1>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- side nav Bar -->
          <div class="col-sm-2 border sidebar-content" style="margin-top:55px;">
            <h5>list</h5>
            <hr>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>
            <h1>some text</h1>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <!-- bottom player -->
    <nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container" style="width: 50%;height: 40px;">


      </div>
    </nav>


  </body>

</html>
```